# Passing List from Thymeleaf to Spring Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, parameter-passing, thymeleaf

I'm trying to pass a List which is already provided in my Thymeleaf HTML back to the controller after changing the  option. I've tried it with a hidden input, but unfortunately, it's not working yet.

My form looks like this (a List "movies" is already provided by the controller)

```html
<form action="/movies" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{movies}" name="movies"/>
    <select name="myselect" id="myselect" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option value="1">Sort by Name (A-Z)</option>
        <option value="2">Sort by Name (Z-A)</option>
        <option value="3">Newest First</option>
        <option value="4">Oldest First</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

And my Controller looks like this:

```
package at.spengergasse.omdbspring.controller;

import at.spengergasse.omdbspring.domain.Movie;
import at.spengergasse.omdbspring.service.MovieService;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

@RequiredArgsConstructor

@Controller
public class MoviesController {
    private final MovieService movieService;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String greeting(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("movies", movieService.findAll());
        return "movies";
    }

    @PostMapping("/movies")
    public String getMoviesOrdered(@RequestAttribute List<Movie> movies, @RequestParam String myselect, Model model){
        model.addAttribute(movieService.findCustomListSorted(movies,myselect));
        return "movies";
    }
}
```

Looking forward to someone you is able to help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the same issue in my Project Where the Hidden List value is already provided by Controller and then the same value needs to be passed further to controller.
I've got it resolved using @ModelAttribute annotation (I'm pasting same code of mine as per your Requirements) :---

1.) Create an object of the form (which needs to send further to controller after form submit) on the controller where you're sending the movies :-

```
    model.addAttribute("some_value", new YourDesiredJavaClass());
```

---

2.) Create Thymeleaf object on the form by the same name - "some_value" in this case :--

```
<form action="/movies" th:object="${some_value}" method="POST">
    <input th:field="${movies}" type="hidden" ></input>
</form>
```

---

3.) get the List from Thymleaf To controller . :--

```
 @PostMapping("movies")
         public String getMovies(@ModelAttribute("some_value") YourDesiredJavaClass requestClass, Model model) {
```

// further code ..

}

---

4.) Create the Request class with setter & getter methods . :---

```
  public class YourDesiredJavaClass{

       private List<String> movies;

      //setter & getter methods

    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Of course I adjust it a little bit for my needs but the concept is like this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As your list of movies is sent by your form, it will be available in HTTP POST body. So you have to use `@RequestBody` instead of `@RequestAttribute`.

```
@PostMapping("/movies")
public String getMoviesOrdered(@RequestBody List<Movie> movies, @RequestParam String myselect, Model model){
    model.addAttribute(movieService.findCustomListSorted(movies,myselect));
    return "movies";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, if I am doing so I get an error:
`Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported`

Comment: Your request mapping have to specify that it consumes `application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8`. You can do so by adding `consumes="application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"`. For example : `@PostMapping("/movies", consumes="application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8")`

Comment: I changed that now but still getting the error.
My Controller looks like this now:
`@PostMapping(value="/movies", consumes="application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8")
    public String getMoviesOrdered(@RequestBody List<Movie> movies, @RequestParam String myselect, Model model){
        model.addAttribute(movieService.findCustomListSorted(movies,myselect));
        return "movies";
    }`

Comment: you may need to change it to `"application/json; charset=utf-8"`

Comment: Still... is there maybe a problem with the form in the html ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to call on a list of movies when you click a select field, and add the movies to some div? This can be done by an AJAX call to the controller, so that upon completion it will then populate the div with the content, if that makes sense:

```
    function getMoviesOrdered(myselect){
    var prep = {};
    prep['movies'] = myselect;

    var data = JSON.stringify(prep);
    $.ajax({
  url:"/movies",
  type:"POST",
  data:data,
  contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType:"json",
  error:function(){},
  complete:function(data){
  document.getElementById("#someDivId").innerHTML = data;
  }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
Yeah, this could be right if I want to change the div instantly out of the HTML. In this case, I don't want to use AJAX instead my goal is it to pass the List Back to the Java @Controller and handle it there.

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestBody List<Movie> movies
```

worked for me only when I added

```
consumes="application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

which is not always what you want to do. Also the accepted answer with the wrapper object works, but it would be simpler just to declare global variable for all controller methods:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Controller
public class MoviesController {
    private final MovieService movieService;
    private final Set<Movie> movieSet = new HashSet<>();

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String greeting(Model model) {
        movieSet.addAll("movies", movieService.findAll());
        model.addAttribute("movies", movieSet);
        return "movies";
    }

    @PostMapping("/movies")
    public String getMoviesOrdered(@RequestParam String myselect, Model model){
        model.addAttribute(movieService.findCustomListSorted(movieSet, myselect));
        return "movies";
    }
}
```

and populate or read the list in each method.